# How to use abstract class in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Starting out with EF Core, I'm trying to use an abstract class. I understand that I can't instantiate an abstract class and have a part of code missing but cannot find how to solve it.

The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ProjectTest1 
{
    public abstract class User 
    {
        [Key]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Student : User 
    {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher : User 
    {
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model : DbContext 
    {
        public static readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
            builder.AddConsole();
        });

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=project")
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            using var model = new Model();
            model.Database.EnsureCreated();

            model.Users.RemoveRange(model.Users);
            model.SaveChanges();

            var guillaume = new Student() 
            {
                FirstName = "guillaume", 
                LastName = "b", 
                Password = "azerty",
                Email = "guillaume@gmail.com", 
                IsAdmin = true,
                Number = "150200"
            };

            var donald = new Teacher() 
            {
                FirstName = "donald", 
                LastName = "c", 
                Password = "azerty",
                Email = "donald@gmail.com", 
                IsAdmin = false, 
                Salary = 35000
            };

            model.Users.AddRange(new User[] { guillaume, donald });
            model.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

The execution of the code produce error:

> System.InvalidOperationException
> HResult=0x80131509
>
> Message=The corresponding CLR type for entity type 'User' cannot be instantiated, and there is no derived entity type in the model that corresponds to a concrete CLR type.
>
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> StackTrace:
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateClrInheritance(IModel model, IEntityType entityType, HashSet`1 validEntityTypes)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateClrInheritance(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IModel model) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IModel model) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IModel model) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType) at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_Dependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
> at ProjectTest1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\yamab\Desktop\ProjectTest1\ProjectTest1\Program.cs:line 48

Reading this [tutorial](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) I think I should do something like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .Map<Studentt>(m => m.Requires("User").HasValue("S"))
                .Map<Teacher>(m => m.Requires("Usre").HasValue("T"));
}
```

Not sure this is what I should do nor how to do it exactly?

Comment: If you want a "User" Entity, it cannot be abstract.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for your reply. why in the tutorial I mentioned it seem to be done or how then should I do to use student and teacher extending user?

Comment: `User` can only be `abstract` if it itself is not an Entity. So, if in your tutorial, some class is abstract, then you are doing something differently than in the tutorial.

Comment: Aw, wait a second. ... "Table per Hierarchy" ... that article is from 2010, so probably refers to Entity Framework, _not_ EF **Core**. Are you using EF Core? AFAIK, there are some of these concepts, that are not (yet) supported in EF Core as opposed to Entity Framework.

Comment: You might find this useful [Types of Entities in Entity Framework](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Types-of-Entities.aspx)

Comment: @Fildor yes, EF Core as I said just starting out so I don't know about differences with other versions, I thought EF and EF Core was the same thing, sorry about that. 
So what, basically I must create two concrete classes student and teacher even though they just have very few different attributes?

Comment: Here is a resource that refers to EF Core : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance and, yes: it is really not so obvious for newbies, but EF and EF Core are two separate things, actually. They "do" the same, but EF Core being the "shiny new better reboot" of EF, it hasn't quite all the features of its older sibling.

Comment: @Fildor I will read those resources, thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 4):

Thank you to @Fildor for the assistance and pointing me to [Entity type hierarchy mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance)

The solution was to add

```
public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
```

Complet code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ProjectTest1 {

    public abstract class User {
        [Key]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }

    }

    public class Student : User {
        public string Number { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teacher : User {
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Model : DbContext {

        public static readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => {
            builder.AddConsole();
        });
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=project")
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .UseLoggerFactory(_loggerFactory);
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            using var model = new Model();
            model.Database.EnsureCreated();

            model.Users.RemoveRange(model.Users);
            model.SaveChanges();

            var guillaume = new Student() {
                FirstName = "guillaume", LastName = "b", Password = "azerty",
                Email = "guillaume@gmail.com", IsAdmin = true , Number = "150200"
            };
            var donald = new Teacher() {
                FirstName = "donald", LastName = "c", Password = "azerty",
                Email = "donald@gmail.com", IsAdmin = false, Salary = 35000
            };

            model.Users.AddRange(new User[] { guillaume, donald });
            model.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
}
```